# How many ways to visit $6$ cities twice?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

A person wishes to visit $6$ cities, each exactly twice, and never visiting the same city twice in a row. In how many ways can this be done ?

---

I tried by inclusion exclusion.

But Having a problem in finding the total number of outcomes ?

I guess total number of outcomes can be found by using multinomial coefficients like 
$(12!)/(2!)(2!)(2!)(2!)(2!)(2!)$.

---

Am i proceeding correct ?

Comment: Do not confuse the phrases **probability** with **number of outcomes**.

Comment: @JMoravitz ohh. My Bad.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for the edit. Am I right here ?

Comment: Well, the denominator is now correct, and if you have applied PIE correctly, so should the numerator be.

Answer (score 1):

**Proceeding via inclusion-exclusion**: There are $2^{n-6}(12-n)!$ arrangements in which $n$ particular cities are visited twice in a row, so there are
$$
2^{-6}\sum_{n=0}^6(-2)^n\binom6n(12-n)!=2631600
$$
arrangements in which no city is visited twice in a row.